# iAd & Admob integration

Tags: iphone, integration, admob, iad

I integrated iAd / Admob display code from the link from here: http://www.apptite.be/tutorial_mixing_ads.php
and had some weird results.  On admob, my click through rate dropped 40%, but the number of impressions stayed the same.  Its as if both ads are shown at the same time, with iAds on top of admob ads.  Does anyone see problems with the code on that site that could possibly cause that?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I would recommend using a mediation solution to implement multiple ad networks instead of rolling your own home-brew solution.  AdMob's latest SDK includes [ad network mediation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/ios/mediation/), and iAd is one of the supported ad networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly we should download Admob Sdk from google.
That file is required In google AdMob API :-

GADAdSize.h
GADBannerView.h
GADBannerViewDelegate.h
GADInterstitial.h
GADInterstitial.h
GADRequest.h
GADRequestError.h
libGoogleAdMobAds

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GADBannerViewDelegate.h"

@class GADBannerView, GADRequest;

@interface BannerExampleViewController : UIViewController
    <GADBannerViewDelegate> {
  GADBannerView *adBanner_;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) GADBannerView *adBanner;

- (GADRequest *)createRequest;

@end


#import "BannerViewController.h"
#import "GADBannerView.h"
#import "GADRequest.h"

@implementation BannerExampleViewController

@synthesize adBanner = adBanner_;

#pragma mark init/dealloc

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view,
// typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0,
                               self.view.frame.size.height -
                               CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner).height);
  self.adBanner = [[[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner
                                                  origin:origin]
                    autorelease];

  self.adBanner.adUnitID = AdMob key;
  self.adBanner.delegate = self;
  [self.adBanner setRootViewController:self];
  [self.view addSubview:self.adBanner];
  [self.adBanner loadRequest:[self createRequest]];
}

- (void)dealloc {
  adBanner_.delegate = nil;
  [adBanner_ release];
  [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark GADRequest generation

- (GADRequest *)createRequest {
  GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
  request.testing = YES;
  return request;
}

#pragma mark GADBannerViewDelegate impl

- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)adView {
  NSLog(@"Received ad successfully");
}

- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view
    didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {
  NSLog(@"Failed to receive ad with error: %@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, so I'm looking at the code that says:

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"iAdBanner failed");

    // Only request adMob when iAd did fail
    [self adMobRequest];
```

And on Apple's site, it says that "Even after an error is sent to your delegate, the banner view continues to try to download new advertisements. Thus, implementing both of these delegate methods allows your application to display the banner only when advertisements are loaded." ([link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html))

I'm guessing that what is happening is that if iAd fails, you're displaying an AdMob ad, but then iAd is also retrying as well and so if it fails again, it is requesting another AdMob ad despite the fact that one may already be getting shown?